# Notepad++ regex search and replace assistance

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've dug around for about half an hour trying to find a way to do this, but I'm far from good with regex and ... well, am giving up.  I turn to my peers for some help.

I've got a large text file that has a bunch of xml like values in it and I need to completely remove the entries.

All the entries start with, for example, `<junktag *>` (Important to note the asterisk I think, because it's an operator in regex), and end with `</junktag>`.

For example:  Find all instances of this (except the text in the middle differs between entries), and delete it out of the file.

```
<junktag *>
randomgibberish=yes
randomgibberese=no
</junktag>
```

I've tried:

```
\<junktag *>*\</junktag>
```

But that doesn't seem to be working right.  I'm thinking I need a way to escape the regex operators.

Comment: How about `<junktag.*</junktag>`?

Comment: Well, There are other entries - such as <junktag b> that I don't want to replace.  I only want to replace the <junktag *> entries.

Comment: Did you google for a way to escape regex operators? It does have an escape character (the backslash). '\*' in a regex means a literal asterisk.

Comment: I read that / should escape operators, but it isn't working.  I've tried `<junktag *>.*</junktag>` and `<junktag /*>.*</junktag>` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tested in notepad++ 6.3.2 with the dotall mode:

```
<junktag \*>.*?</junktag>
```

Comment: As he already said, he doesn't want to remove e.g. `<junktag a>...</junktag>`.

Comment: Trying to google what dotall mode is now, but your second example, as Lukas pointed out, would not work for my application.

Comment: Note the lazy operator (is it called like this?) `?`, else this will be greedy and remove everything between first `<junktag *>` and last `</junktag>`

Comment: @miR:dotall is only a checkbox in your search window, which means that the dot can match new line, you must check it. Corrected for the second example.

Comment: @Lukas: question mark have been added when you wrote your comment, sorry, but thanks.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Just noticed... the resources I found where outdated and written when n++ didn't support this.

Comment: Was running notepad 5.9.x - Just downloaded 6.3.3 and I now see the . matches newline option.